# Проблема с кодировкой: вопросительные знаки вместо русских букв

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема с кодировкой при отсылке письма. У меня все нормально, программа работает, но когда сохраняю какие-то данные на русском, то показывает вопросительные знаки.

Comment: С первым апреля! 

    cout<<"С первым апреля!";//? ?????? ??????!

Comment: не понял ответ

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, куда посылаете? куда сохраняются? в какой кодировке? и где именно показываются вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте перед запросами к базе данных делать

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Зайди в phpmyadmin и настрой кодировку БД на utf или cp1251